# Is it possible to add elements to React's Virtual DOM but use jQuery for append to the real DOM?

Tags: jquery, reactjs

I'm using a jquery plugin called gridalicious for displaying my images in a grid style similar to collages, this works pretty good in the first rendering, when I call it in the componentDidUpdate method, this applies the style to my elements and displays them correctly...

Now the problem is that when I need update the gallery and add new elements, gridalicious includes its own method to add new elements avoiding changes of position and size of the previously loaded images....

```js
$('#append').click(function(){
  $("#example3").gridalicious('append', makeboxes());
});
```

my initial idea was to add these images to my state, React would be (and actually is) smart to notice that there only needs to append a few images, and then run again the library to customize the size and position. The trouble is that when I did this, my previous images were modified for the library and change their size,look and even position... notice than the grid library applies some algorithms to determinate which are the best sizes, positions and order for sorting the images and displaying them obtaining the collage effect...

I suppose that I need to avoid that react renders again the gallery (using shouldComponentUpdate I guess) and to add my new components using the jquery lib, I need the bindings of react because when I click on the images, information and other details appear, so I need really the power of react but I need to find a way as to how integrate both libs, thanks!!...

just now the site seems be down I hope it will be fixed soon suprb.com/apps/gridalicious/‎  thanks so much!!!...

Comment: You might be interested in my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20035981/49485.

Comment: yes...seems than this will be more complicated than I was expected, although the source code for the jquery lib is short I can't see how integrate react with it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These sort of interactions must be handled outside React. When I have to do these kind of things I use the life cycle methods `componentDidMount` and `componentDidUpdate` to manipulate the DOM with jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of attaching gridalicious outside of the virtual DOM in componentDidMount, you could enclose gridalicious within a React Component as seen in this similar [jQuery UI interop example](https://github.com/ryanflorence/reactconf-2015-HYPE/blob/master/demos/04-dom-lib-interop/app.js).