# Vue js v-model inside a bootstrap popover content

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, vue.js

I'm stuck trying to get an input with a v-model to work inside a bootstrap popover. The current result is an unbound input. Note that mustaches are  being correctly evaluated there. Here is a code sample:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://vuejs.org/js/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
This is the expected result
<br>
{{ message }} : 
<input type="text" v-model="message" placeholder="edit me">

<hr>
This is the bootstrap result:<br>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="popover" title="Popover title" data-content="" data-placement="right auto">Click to toggle popover</button>
<div class="hide popper-content">{{ message }} : 
<input type="text" v-model="message"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Now onto js:

```
new Vue({
  el: 'body',
  data: {
    message: 'Hello Vue.js!'
  }
})

$(function () {
  $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
    html: true,
    content: function () {
      return $(this).next('.popper-content').html()
    }
  })
})
```

And here is a little jsbin http://jsbin.com/fadexaxoku/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: I can't even get the popover to work in your example. It looks like the problem might be that when you assign the `content` function for the popover, a copy of the the `.popper-content` is created (which thus lacks the binding).

Comment: @nils1 I don't know why it's not working for you, the jsbin is working fine for me, I just cheked again. The missing binding is in fact the core problem, so far I did not find anyway to get the bindings there, so I switched the thing to a dropdown button in the meantime

Comment: You could try this: https://yuche.github.io/vue-strap/#popover.  Not an answer but could work as an alternative

Comment: Unfortunately, that component suffer from the same issue. The problem seems to be not vue js specific as pointed out by this answer which relate to using a react component within a bootstrap popover: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20035981/5932512

Answer (score 2):

try this one which persist the reference.

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: 'Hello Vue.js!'
 }
})

$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
    html: true,
    content: $('#popper-content')
  }).on('show.bs.popover', function() {
    $('#popper-content').addClass('show')
  }).on('hide.bs.popover', function() {
    $('#popper-content').addClass('hide')
  })
});
```

we are binding event to add 'hide' class as we are showing real element so we need to do it manually but it works.

live code :

http://jsbin.com/dajucowuqi/1/edit?html,js,output

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: 'Hello Vue.js!'
  }
})

$(function () {
  $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
    html: true,
    content: $('#popper-content')
  }).on('show.bs.popover', function() {
    $('#popper-content').addClass('show')
  }).on('hide.bs.popover', function() {
    $('#popper-content').addClass('hide')
  })
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://vuejs.org/js/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="app">
      {{ message }} : 
      <input type="text" v-model="message" placeholder="edit me">
      <br>     
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="popover" title="Popover title" data-content="" data-placement="right auto">Click to toggle popover</button>
      <div id="popper-content" class="hide popper-content">{{ message }} : 
        <input type="text" v-model="message">
      </div>
  </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Very nice answer, it finally helped me to do what i wanted with vue.js and bootstrap4 popover. For bootstrap 4, classes are now `d-none` and `d-block` instead of `hide` and `show`. I personally hide the popper content on `hide.bs.popover` event, so the animation can be smoothly processed before the content is made invisible.

Also, I use `addClass("d-none")` after hiding the popover and `removeClass("d-none")` before showing, which provide the same result. Thanks again !!

Comment: I meant `hidden.bs.popover` instead of `hide.bs.popover`, to let the animation run before hiding content